# Funcion AS Trigger can`t update

Tags: triggers, postgis, new-operator

I have a little problem and stack in something easy...

Working with postgis -> in Qgis.
I have Table

```
    CREATE TABLE public."Table"
(
    "ID" bigint NOT NULL,
    geom geometry NOT NULL,
    typ_obudowy text,
    PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
);

ALTER TABLE public."Table"
    OWNER to jcorp_admin;

GRANT ALL ON TABLE public."Table" TO j_admin WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT ALL ON TABLE public."Table" TO j_projektant;

GRANT ALL ON TABLE public."Table" TO jcorp_admin WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER TABLE_t 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE  
ON "schem1"."Table" FOR EACH ROW  
EXECUTE PROCEDURE "schem1".Table_f();
```

and funkction:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "schem1".Table_f() 
RETURNS trigger AS 
$BODY$  
DECLARE 
BEGIN 

CASE TG_OP 

WHEN 'INSERT' THEN

    UPDATE "schem1"."Table" SET fild1 = 'wpisz tekst' WHERE "schem1"."Table"."id" = '3';
    UPDATE "schem1"."Table" SET fild2 = 'wprowadz' WHERE "schem1"."Table"."id" = NEW.id; RETURN NULL; WHEN 'UPDATE' THEN

RETURN NULL; 

WHEN 'DELETE' THEN

RETURN NULL; 

END CASE; 

RETURN NULL; END; 
$BODY$   
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

And still got error.

> Nie można zatwierdzić zmian dla warstwy skrzynki_cad

Błędy: BŁĄD: nie dodano 1 obiektu.

Błędy dostawcy:
Błąd PostGIS podczas dodawania obiektów: ERROR:  column "fild1" of relation "Table" does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE "schem1"."Table" SET field1 = 'wpisz tek...
^
QUERY:  UPDATE "schem1"."Table" SET field1 = 'wpisz tekst' WHERE "schem1"."Table"."id" = '3'
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function schem1.Table_f() line 8 at SQL statement

Comment: Welcome to SO. Are you sure that the table `schem1.table` really exist? Could you also add the create table statement? Unrelated note: get rid of the double quotes around table and schema names!

Comment: Hi,
yes it exist. It was created by Qgis... and I see it in pgAdmin. 
I was try without ""

Comment: There is problem with NEW. 
i just try to do it simple :
 UPDATE public."Table" SET typ_obudowy = 'bzzzzyk';  
it is change by new record. 
But can no write with .NEW 
 UPDATE public."Table" SET field1 = 'bzzzzyk' WHERE public."Table"."id" = NEW.id ; 
 RETURN NULL

Comment: ok, I find problem.
problem is with postgis and Geometry. 
For layer as polygon it`s all fine, for points trigger don`t whan`t to work